# Condition for 1 to be between the roots of a function.

Tags: inequality

Q. Find the range of value of x for which 1 lies between the roots of the equation.

$3y^2-(3sinx)y -2cos^2x=0$

By IVT, we know that $f(1)<0$,

$3y^2-(3sin1)y-2cos^2(1)=0$ should have roots which are less than zero, however, after finding the values of y using quadratic formula, there is a fixed value of y, so I'm not able to figure out how can we get the range of x?

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to apply the quadratic formula to your first equation, so you obtain roots as a function of $x$.  Then, since you know which root is larger, determine if the lesser is less than 1 is less than the greater...

Comment: You have two symbols $x$ and $y$ in your formula. When you say "the roots", are you referring to values of $y$? One would expect so. Then you say this means $f(1) = 0$; is that a function $f$ evaluated at $y = 1$? If not, what is it, and why? And if $f(1)$ means evaluate $f$ at $y = 1$, why did you instead set $x = 1$ in the next formula?

Comment: @DavidK, sorry, I think I have misinterpreted the question, I took the roots as the values of $x$, instead of values of y,  how do we get to know which has to be considered as roots? both of x,y are equally good

Comment: Honestly it isn't a very clear question. No wonder you ran into difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

The question requires some thought just to figure out what it is asking for.

We're supposed to find a range of values of $x$ for which a certain property is true, so let's suppose we found one value of $x$ in that range, let's call it $x_0,$ and now we should find that when $x = x_0$ then $1$ lies between the roots of the equation
$$ 3y^2 - (3\sin x)y - 2\cos^2 x = 0. $$

In other words $1$ lies between the roots of
$ 3y^2 - (3\sin x_0)y - 2\cos^2 x_0 = 0 $ where $x_0$ is the particular number we hypothetically found earlier; so this equation is just a quadratic in $y$ with (hypothetically) known coefficients, and the roots are values of $y$ that solve the equation.

So now we've established (apparently) that the "roots" we're looking for are roots of a simple quadratic equation $ay^2 + by + c = 0$
where it just happens that $b = -3\sin x$ and $c = -2 \cos^2 x.$

The roots are (as usual)
$$
y_+ = \frac{-b + \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}, \quad
y_- = \frac{-b - \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}.
$$
Since $b^2 - 4ac = 9\sin^2 + 24\cos^2 x$ and $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are never zero at the same value of $x,$ we know that $b^2 - 4ac > 0$ for every $x$ and so there are always two roots of the quadratic equation.

We also know that $-\frac{b}{2a}$ is midway between the two roots, but since
$$ -\frac{b}{2a} = -\frac{(-3\sin x)}{2(3)} = \frac12 \sin x, $$
we know that $y_- < 1$ for every $x,$ so the question is just when
$y_+ > 1$ (assuming "between" means strictly between, that is, assuming we do not want $x$ such that one of the roots is $1$).

So it comes down to the solution set for $x$ in the inequality below,
which we get by making the substitution above for $y_+$ in the inequality $y_+ > 1$
and then making substitutions for $a,$ $b,$ and $c$:
$$
\frac{3\sin x + \sqrt{9 \sin^2 x - 24 \cos^2 x}}{6} > 1.
$$

This is still not a trivial problem, but it is unambiguous and solvable.